# I can type in Google Chrome only, any other application does not receive keyboard input (just beeps). Possibly Radeon update made this

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, amd-radeon

I don't understand what is happening. I saw that my CPU was consumed by Radeon install (no idea, what is that, I have not used it consciously). After that Radeon desktop opened as soon as I type 'r' in the Google URL edit field. I managed to overcome this by changing the language back to ENG/INTL or ENG/UK.

But other 2 issues remain and those are very strange:

- I can write normally in Google URL and form fields (as I am writing this). But when I open any other file (Notepad, Word, etc.), then those files are not receiving any keyboard click, my computer just beeps;
- I used the left eye of the mouse to open documents and folders with double click - I guess  - majority of users do this, this is a default behavior. But now the double click with the left eye opens the properties dialog for the file or folder.

I have experienced a lot, but the basics things usually worked smoothly so far. Now these are gone.

I am using Dell laptop, Windows 10 and there is Radeon Graphics. Actually I don't know anything about Radeon, but I have this window and the label on my laptop.

Thanks for any help and suggestions. Any serious work is not impossible from my laptop.

**Update.** I did nothing. Though I can say, that there was message 'Windows can't finish download updates'. It says this from time to time and then it finds the way to install updates anyway. I am usually using Hibernate option of my laptop, so, the real restart can be once or month or even rare. But now the problem is gone. The programs receive keyboard keys normally and the left eye of the mouse works normally. Huhs, it was so scary!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  No question to answer

Comment: Actually I would be happy to know what happened. It was scary and I didnt like to be helpless.

Comment: Radeon is a graphics processor brand from AMD. Your computer has a Radeon graphics "card" (or chip, or APU, etc). Essentially, that software was a graphics driver, and it was pushed by Windows Update, or you're running Dell's update utility. While drivers or other significant patches are installing, it is not uncommon for some things to change or work oddly or incorrectly. This is just one of MANY reasons why IT people will suggest you restart your computer before continuing a complaint. Adding to that, waiting for installs to complete and then restarting will do even better.

Comment: Your computer was likely experiencing normal but odd (and definitely surprising and frustrating) symptoms of a patch/driver install. Next time this happens, if you see an installer is running, check the internet to understand WHAT is installing, if it's legit, wait for it to finish, restart your computer, and THEN if the issue persists, seek further advice.